# React-select get selected option label as strin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

When trying to use an icon for an option it seems to be passed as JSX in the `onChange` handler. Anyway to get hold of original `label` in option prior to injecting image in the `onChange` handler? Or is there a way to get hold of index of selected option.

[image]

Here's a sample https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-label-icon-forked-52djv

Answer (score 0):

Using `formatOptionWithImage` solves the problem.

Example
https://codesandbox.io/embed/reactselect-formatoptionlabel-bde1q